# Managing critical errors: logging & email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, logging, actionmailer

What's the best way to send quick one-liner e-mails to an administrative address in Rails?

I am using the Rails `Logger` to keep track of nasty problems in my application.  One of my controllers is doing mission-critical work and I need to know of any errors ASAP.  When there is an error, I would like my app to send an email to myself, calling attention to the log containing more details.  I'm envisioning something like the following pseudo-code:

```
begin
   ...
rescue
   logger.error("Found an error!  Params hash is " + params.to_s)
   email("user@example.com","Critical error in log.  Investigate line " + len(logger.error).to_s)
end
```

The obvious first place I looked at was [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html).  However, both the documentation and [my literature](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails) talk about creating a mailer Model, View & Controller, which seems overly complex for what I want:  A very short (one-line) e-mail to an email address where formatting & reply-to address doesn't matter at all.  This brings me back to my question:  What's the best way to send quick one-liner e-mails to an administrative e-mail address in Rails?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Pony](http://adam.blog.heroku.com/past/2008/11/2/pony_the_express_way_to_send_email_from_ruby/) gem (as in Pony Express), which is a lightweight alternative to ActionMailer:

```
require 'pony'
Pony.mail(:to => 'user@example.com', :from => 'railsapp@example.com',
          :subject => 'Critical error in log')
```

Alternatively, you could sign up for a free account with [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/) and raise an exception from your application. They'll capture it and send you an email.

Comment: Voting up for the Hoptoad suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of exception notification plugins for Rails: http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/exception_notification.html

Comment: http://github.com/rails/exception_notification is crazy simple to set up.